# How to pick out calls to methods with default visibility?

Tags: aop, aspectj

It is possible to pick out calls to methods with any of the three visibility-modifiers, e.g.

```
call(public * TestClass.*(..));
```

but not for those with default visibility.
I can think of this way around it:

```
    pointcut bla():
        call(!public * TestClass.*(..))
        && call(!protected * TestClass.*(..))
        && call(!private * TestClass.*(..));
```

Still, I was wondering if there is no shorter way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
// Intercept caller
pointcut packageVisibleMethodCall() :
    call(!private !public !protected * *(..));

// Intercept callee
pointcut packageVisibleMethodExecution() :
    execution(!private !public !protected * *(..));
```